# Найти город в строке js

Tags: javascript

Есть строки, к примеру:

```
var a = 'Нижний НовгородВК "Нижегородская Ярмарка" (просмотр) пав. 3';
var b = 'Санкт-ПетербургКонгрессный бизнес-центр "Петроконгресс" (просмотр)';
```

Есть массив с городами:

```
var arr = ["Санкт-Петербург", "Нижний Новгород", "Москва"]
```

Каким образом можно найти совпадение в строке с каким-либо элементом массива? Т.е. чтобы после определенных действий в строке `a` остался лишь `Нижний Новгород`?

Comment: Возможно можно пройтись по массиву городов циклом и проверить, входит ли город в строку с помощью метода [`String.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains)

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, строки у Вас в массиве? Не в переменных же?

Comment: @IgorLut да, верно

Answer (score 0):

Самый "примитивный" способ, попробуйте. Единственное, Вы должны быть уверены, что в массивах не будет опечаток. Например, Москва и москва будут не равны. В этом случае нужно будет привести все в один регистр.

```js
var arrOfStrings = ['Нижний НовгородВК "Нижегородская Ярмарка" (просмотр) пав. 3', 'Санкт-ПетербургКонгрессный бизнес-центр "Петроконгресс" (просмотр)'];
var arrOfCities = ["Санкт-Петербург", "Нижний Новгород", "Москва"];

for(let i = 0; i < arrOfStrings.length; i++){
 for(let k = 0; k < arrOfCities.length; k++){
    //если есть совпадение, перезаписываем элемент в массиве строк
  if(arrOfStrings[i].indexOf(arrOfCities[k]) >= 0) {
   arrOfStrings[i] = arrOfCities[k];
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Далеко не идеальный вариант, но как рабочая идея. Надеюсь, я правильно понял Вашу проблему.

```js
var a = 'Нижний НовгородВК "Нижегородская Ярмарка" (просмотр) пав. 3';
var b = 'Санкт-ПетербургКонгрессный бизнес-центр "Петроконгресс" (просмотр)';
var mas = [a, b];   // массив строк

var arr = ["Санкт-Петербург", "Нижний Новгород", "Москва"];
for (var j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {  // проход по каждой строке
    for (var i = 0; i < (arr.length); i++) {  // проход по каждому городу
        var string = mas[j];
        var x = string.indexOf(arr[i]);
        if (x > -1) {
            mas[j] = arr[i]; // если город есть в строке, то он становится этой строкой
        }
    }
}

alert(mas);
```